# How to use full width in Maui

Tags: c#, maui

I often run into confusion when I try to make something take up the full width of a page. For example - I want to draw a line from one side to the other. I have tried with Border and BoxView. However, without setting a WidthRequest all I get is a dot in the middle of the page.

Obviously I don't want to set a fixed width...

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<Border BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the parent of the control. It also depends on the layout it is part of.

Comment: It is inside a VerticalStackLayout, which is inside a ScrollLayout

Answer (score 2):

Removing `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` also fills the entire width

```
<Border x:Name="border" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="50"/>
```

Or set `HorizontalOptions` to "FillAndExpand":

```
<Border x:Name="border" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Comment: FillAndExpand is deprecated in MAUI

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the behaviour of controls in different Layouts.
I will specifically go into the border's details.

IMO border is designed to hold a control. The Following examples assume that you use a VerticalStackLayout as mentioned in your post.

### Using a border with content

In this example the border automatically fills the entire width, since its child (Label) fills the entire width

```
<Border Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="2,2">
     <Label Text="Test" />
</Border>
```

### Using border to create a line (IMO dont do it)

You could cheat a little with setting the HeightRequest to 3. But then the color is grayish. Using 3 works probably because the strokethickness is 1 so the inner part has a height of 1 if you substract top and bottom border.

```
<Border BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="3"/>
```

You could also do, but the result is a mix of both colors.

```
<Border BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="1  " Stroke="blue" StrokeThickness="0.3"/>
```

### Using Line

Instead of using a border you should use a line, since it is exactly designed for this purpose.

```
<Line BackgroundColor="Black"/>
```